# bivariate standard normal variable in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, normal-distribution

I have a question about bivariate standard normal random variable.

Suppose

```
M(x,y,rho)=P
```

(X is less than x,Y is less than y) where X and Y are bivariate standard normal random variables with correlation rho.

How can I solve M in Python. Suppose I want to solve`M(1,3,0.9`). How can I solve it in Python?

I have searched numpy.random.multivariate_normal, but I am still confused.

Comment: Pretend you're talking to programmers, not mathematicians. I have no idea what a "bivariate standard normal" variable is. I know "rho" is a greek letter, though!

Comment: this is actually not that bad if you're familiar with numpy(and presumably stats)

Comment: Thanks for your guide. Here rho is the correlation between two standard normal distribution, X and Y. I am not that familiar with numpy. I googled but did not find the right solution to it. I will appreciate it if you can give me more detailed guide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: M(x,y,rho)=P(X is less than x, Y is less than y) where X and Y follow standard normal distribution and the correlation between X and Y is rho.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compute the CDF of a multivariate normal distribution.  Here is a way to do it:

```
from scipy.stats import mvn
import numpy as np
low = np.array([-100, -100])
upp = np.array([1, 3])
mu = np.array([0, 0])
S = np.array([[1,0.9],[0.9,1]])
p,i = mvn.mvnun(low,upp,mu,S)
print p
```

The low bound array is an approximation in negative infinity. You can make those numbers more negative if you want more precision.

Comment: Thanks very much ! It is exactly what I need here.